# how to add row number base on group in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

i am trying to add new column name row number as Sr.No in my ssrs report but number is not coming in proper way .

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COaMN.png)

i have used =RunningValue(Fields!Party.Value,CountDistinct,"DrCr") this formula for row number "DrCr" means Debit/Credit Group . I have also used function :-

```
Public rn as integer
  Public Function GetRn() AS Integer
   rn = rn +1
    return rn
  End Function
```

=Code.GetRn

but it give result like

|  | header |
| --- | --- |
| Group | 1 |
|  | 2 |
| Group | 3 |
|  | 4 |

I want groupwise number

|  | header |
| --- | --- |
| Group | 1 |
|  | 2 |
| Group | 1 |
|  | 2 |

Comment: please supply some sample data as text and expected results based on that sample data.

Comment: I have grouped (Row Group) my table on Column 1 and Column 2. This is ok but the Sr.No column shows row number of grouped row 
e.g .
`Group.Name `
**1,2,3,4**
`GroupName`
**5,6**
so on. I want to the Sr.No or row number group wise . 

`Group.Name`
**1,2,3,4**
`GroupName`
**1,2**